# grails NullPointerException saving bi-directional one-to-many relationship model

Tags: json, hibernate, grails, data-binding, one-to-many

I have the following two simple models creating a bidirectional one-to-many relationship in a Grails 2.4.3 application:

```
class Player {
  String firstName
  String lastName
  String position

  static belongsTo = [team: Team]
}

class Team {
  String name
  List players = new ArrayList()

  static hasMany = [players: Player]

  static mapping= {
    players cascade:"all-delete-orphan"
  }

}
```

I would like to be able to save and update teams and their associated players via nested JSON, like so:

```
{
  name    : "team A",
  players : [
    {
      firstName : "john",
      lastName  :"doe",
      position  : "center"
    }
  ]
}
```

My TeamController save action looks like this:

```
def save() {
  def team = new Team(request.JSON)
  team.save()
  respond team
}
```

When I make a request with that JSON, I get an error:

```
curl -X POST -d '{name:"team a",players:[{firstName:"john",lastName:"doe",position:"center"}]}' http://localhost:8080/team-test/team/save.json --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

Produces this output in console:

```
| Error 2014-11-14 10:32:26,111 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [POST] /team-test/team/save.json
Stacktrace follows:
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>    8 | save      in team.test.TeamController$$EOvbjH0K
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Because that's a rather vague message, I put a try/catch around the team.save() call in the TeamController and print out the stack trace:

```
def save() {
  def team = new Team(request.JSON)
  try {
    team.save()
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace()
  }
  respond team
}

Error java.lang.NullPointerException
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.BatchFetchQueue.removeBatchLoadableEntityKey(BatchFetchQueue.java:163)
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addEntity(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:388)
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addEntity(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:461)
| Error     at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.makeEntityManaged(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:143)
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:201)
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
| Error     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:684)
| Error     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:676)
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:235)
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
| Error     at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:460)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:294)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
| Error     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
| Error     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:684)
| Error     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:676)
| Error     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:671)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.SavePersistentMethod$1.doInHibernate(SavePersistentMethod.java:58)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:179)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:123)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.SavePersistentMethod.performSave(SavePersistentMethod.java:56)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractSavePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractSavePersistentMethod.java:215)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:68)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormInstanceApi.save(HibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:156)
| Error     at team.test.Team$$EOvbjH0K.save(Team.groovy)
| Error     at team.test.Team$$DOvbjH0K.save(Unknown Source)
| Error     at team.test.Team.save(Team.groovy)
| Error     at team.test.Team$save.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
| Error     at team.test.TeamController$$EOvbkj0y.save(TeamController.groovy:9)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReloadedTypeInvoker$2.invoke(ReloadedTypeInvoker.java:122)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1299)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(MixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:154)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:375)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:252)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:205)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:126)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:72)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:347)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
| Error     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
| Error     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
| Error     at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:178)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:144)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:135)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:216)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
| Error     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
| Error     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
| Error     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
| Error     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

For further investigation, I put some logging in the controller action to see what's going on within the object:

```
def save() {
  JSON.use('deep')

  def team = new Team(request.JSON)
  println "errors? " + team.getErrors()
  println "team: " + team.toString() 
  println ((team as JSON).toString())
  respond team
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
errors? grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors
team: team.test.Team : (unsaved)
{
  "class":"team.test.Team",
  "id":null,
  "name":"team a",
  "players":[
    {
      "class":"team.test.Player",
      "id":null,
      "firstName":"john",
      "lastName":"doe",
      "position":"center",
      "team":null
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there something wrong with my JSON? Why do I get this error? Is it because the team reference is null in the player object? Why is the team reference null in the player object?

Out of curiosity, I removed the belongsTo property from the Player class, and things work as expected...

```
{"class":"team.test.Team","id":2,"name":"team a","players":[{"class":"team.test.Player","id":2}]}
```

Why does it not work in the bidirectional case? What are the different implications of bidirectional and unidirectional in terms of table relationships, data binding, etc? I understand the different cascade strategies when using belongsTo or not in a one-to-many relationship, but both should cascade saves I thought.

I know I'm asking many questions. I need help making this work but would also like to understand what is happening in principle. Help is much appreciated.

edit:
per @th3morg's suggestion I attempted manually building out the Team and Player models and associating them via Team.addToPlayers().

```
def save() {
  JSON.use('deep')

  def teamData = request.JSON

  def team  = new Team()
  team.name = teamData.name

  teamData.players.each { playerData ->
    def player = new Player(playerData)
    team.addToPlayers(player)
  }
  team.save()

  println ((team as JSON).toString())
  respond team
}
```

produces:

```
{"class":"team.test.Team","id":3,"name":"team a","players":[{"class":"team.test.Player","id":3,"firstName":"john","lastName":"doe","position":"center","team":{"_ref":"../..","class":"team.test.Team"}}]}
```

This appears to work, but it is verbose and fragile. Is there no way to achieve the same result through automatic binding or through some other conventional magic?

Comment: Your player object hasn't been saved, so I would think you might get a transient exception instead, but creating a player through the nested json could still be part of problem. As a test, try explicitly creating the player first and then create the team and add the player.

Comment: thanks. updated based on your suggestion, which works but is not an ideal method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case, the reason is straightforward - you need to explicitly call team.addToPlayers(player) before you save. I'm guessing that instantiating a team with the JSON constructor is equivalent to the Map constructor, which is basically equivalent to doing the following:

```
def team = new Team()
team.players = [new Player(), new Player()]
team.save()
```

i.e. setting the players properly directly, rather than calling addToPlayers.
If you run this in a test app, you will get exactly the same exception as you received in your version. This is because (as you've recognized), each Player does not have a back-reference to the Team set (which is what team.addToPlayers()) does. This (strangely) still saves the player object because the Hibernate session flushes when the controller finishes, saving any unsaved instances.

I'd be surprised if removing belongsTo property from the Player class actually fixes the issue - did it actually persist the TeamPlayers relationship? Or did it just *look* like it worked because you were responding with a JSON object where you had effectively manually set the players property?

I realize this is over a year old now, but the reason why I'm commenting is to leave a note for others : there is a (possibly related) known Grails bug which throws the same exception with multiple cascading relationships (e.g. A -> hasMany -> B hasMany -> C) where a child/grandchild has a beforeInsert() or beforeUpdate() method. This may be fixed in Grails 3.x but looks like it will not be fixed in 2.x. - see [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9290) and  [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/698).

Comment: late indeed, but thanks for the good answer anyway. not working on that project anymore and don't recall how I ended up dealing with the issue. I believe you are correct though in that supplying json does a little magic to make a map and then uses the map constructor - seems like, because they have support for bi-directional relationship, maybe grails ought to check and in that case go through calling addTo behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to fix this with a beforeSave() function within your Team domain where you iterate over the players and save each player. This should avoid hibernate trying to save the transient player objects and also prevent you from having to code it yourself in the controller, which is a bit odd feeling.

Also, using GSON, you might be able to avoid any of the addTo associations hibernate would want.

https://github.com/robfletcher/grails-gson#readme